# Make border go to the top of the page under other elements

Tags: html, css

So I have a navigation at the top of my page and a div block underneath it..

What i want is to have the border of the div block go up through the navbar..

Here is a picture to demonstrate what i have so far:

[borderthing http://puu.sh/4pkgO.png](http://puu.sh/4pkgO.png)

Thanks for the help if anyone knows how!

Comment: Post some code also :)

Comment: Any comments on the posted answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof-of-concept example.  The details will differ depending on the actual design.

Start with the following HTML:

```
<div class="nav-wrap">
   <ul class="nav">
       <li>Home</li>
       <li>About This</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and use the following CSS rules:

```css
.nav {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted lightgray; /* for demo only */
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    background-color: white;
}
.nav-wrap {
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    height: 20px;
}
```

The idea is to add a wrapper block around your navigation (`.nav-wrap`) and then set the bottom border to it.  You can then position the border by adjusting the height of the wrapper.

The `.nav` block actually overflows out of the wrapper, but that in this case, it provides a useful effect.

See demo at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AyE5H/)**

**Design Note:** The wrapper block is not strictly necessary but very often, you may need the `ul` block to set an overall height for the navigation bar or some positioning for a multi-level menu.  The wrapper gives you more design options.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the navigation to have absolute positioning or you use z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Give negative value to div margin - KK